# How can I know if I'm close to being banned?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

I've been banned on the superuser site (not for trolling or spamming but for low quality that anyway solved just the technical problem I was posting about) so that my account on superuser is not being accepted for asking question which I've been able to fix by improving the account since improvements are allowed even though I was banned.

I would have been better off with a big red warning that I was close to getting banned but I didn't see it coming even though I knew I was posting mediocre question just to solve a technical problem.

Now I wonder if you can tell me if there's way to get warning if I'm close to being banned?

Comment: Why didn't you ask this on the meta.superuser site? Or are you banned there too?

Comment: Here's my only question on the meta.superuser site http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6427/how-to-clean-low-quality-content. I'm not banned but I can get a warning about "suspicious" on various sites here which works if I reload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no warning, and the details are not public even to mods, but it takes several questions (5-7?) downvoted and closed or deleted, and very few upvotes. If you have downvoted or closed questions, take them as a warning.

Comment: I heard that you can ask as much as you want and I don't disagree with that while naturally I understand that norms must be respected.

Comment: However, the bans are only active on high volume sites. For instance I have certain knowledge that they are not active on Physics.SE which is slightly larger and more active than SciFi.SE.

Comment: @dmckee answer bans are everywhere, question bans aren't.

Comment: You can also get banned from deleting too many of your own questions

Comment: I was just today informed that I could no longer post questions on *Superuser*, so it does still exist. That particulat SE is a "tough room".  I do note that there was a warning note explaining the policy.

Comment: Questions bans _are_ enabled on this site nowadays. You should probably update this answer, since the rest of it and the question are still useful.